# SignalR cross-domain connections with self-hosting and authentication

Tags: signalr, cors, owin

I have a CORS problem when self-hosting SignalR with OWIN, which only happens when I try to enable authentication.

The error I get in my web browser is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.../signalr/negotiate?[snip] Origin ... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

This only happens if I enable authentication in my self-hosted server using the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457382/windows-authentication-with-signalr-and-owin-self-hosting):

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties[typeof(HttpListener).FullName];
  listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm; 

  app.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
}
```

If I comment out the `AuthenticationSchemes` line then CORS works (and I've checked everything in [these instructions](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain)). I get the same problem if I use other authentication schemes than NTLM.

Using Fiddler to examine what's going on, *without* authentication enabled I see the necessary CORS headers coming back from the server:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [my server]

However once I enable authentication I get a 401 response which is missing these headers. All the requests have the necessary `Origin` header.

Having examined the SignalR [source code](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/5bac06a9a76374618df7db0c0b3fa96674208fb3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin/Handlers/CallHandler.cs) it looks like the headers are being set, but presumably with authentication enabled the `HttpListener` is sending the initial 401 response without hitting this code.

So I think my question is: How do I get the `HttpListener` to include an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its negotiation of authentication protocols?

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this? I'm suffering the same issue...

Answer (score 4):

I have gotten NTLM authentication to work with cross domain signalR self-hosted in OWIN by allowing the preflight requests anonymous access.

What one needs to do is create a delegate for choosing the authentication scheme which looks for the preflight request headers, and allows these through anonymously. All other requests will use NTLM.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties[typeof(HttpListener).FullName];
    listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate += AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate;
}

private AuthenticationSchemes AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate(HttpListenerRequest httpRequest)
{
    if (httpRequest.Headers.Get("Access-Control-Request-Method")!=null) 
        return AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
    else 
        return AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems a promising avenue, but my browser doesn't seem to be making preflight requests which means it doesn't actually help. This did inspire me to find the UnsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication property, which nearly achieves something similar (the first request is to a resource which doesn't require CORS, and subsequent requests reuse the authentication from the first). However this falls down after a while because the credentials are cached per TCP connection, and my client evidently ends up opening more than one connection. It's a hack anyway. I'll keep trying...

Comment: Thank you so much! I was tearing my hair out trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you're using Chrome, which very unhelpfully tells you that these headers are missing and that this is the problem, when actually you have probably just forgot to set your `XMLHttpRequest`'s [`withCredentials`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute) property to `true`.

If you're using jQuery you can do this for all requests with:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  options.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };
});
```

You also need to do the right thing with `OPTIONS` requests as in the other answer.